# Eclipse CDT multiuser configuration

Tags: linux, eclipse, configuration, eclipse-cdt

We are trying to setup Eclipse CDT (version Helios or Indigo) for our development environment. It is a multiuser environment, with about 100+ designers using a pool of 10 linux servers. The source code is in Clearcase.

Developers has Windows PCs and use vnc to login to development servers.

One option is using different Eclipse installation on each Windows desktop - but then not sure how complicated setup is to enable remote code browsing/compile/debug/test execution or cross compiling. Is this going to be a IT support/maintenance nightmare?

The other option is to have a single copy of Eclipse on the server and everyone uses the same one. Hoe feasible is this? How difficult is to manage different users' preferences in this setup? Is it possible to have that (different setups) at all? What about required hardware configuration to support this kind of working environment - when multiple sessions are active on the same server at the same time? Is this kind of configuration going to scale?

Which option is better/more suitable for our environment? Any other option that we should consider?

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931337/how-to-handle-eclipse-in-a-multiuser-environment-500) and it is useful but not sure about specific of the development environment that they were trying to address.

I would like to hear some experiences from anyone who managed to successfully set it up in a similar development environment (or tried to do it) and would appreciate any guidelines/recommendations in this regard.

Comment: Install the eclipse development on NFS server, designers login to server to use the eclipse on the NFS server. Only one eclipse instance need be maintained.

Comment: what about performance in this kind of set up? Any additional tune up to ensure no performance hits?

Comment: I am working on a project with about 5 developers. Each one has a local Eclipse installation (in a virtual linux machine, host is Win 7, but that's because the application runs on a linux server). Source code and Eclipse preferences and project files are checked-out from a version control repository. Does this setup answers your question about 'remote code browsing/compile/debug' ?